# Is this a large number problem or a format problem of TclTk?

Tags: formatting, tcl

I am using ActiveTcl 8.6.8 on Windows 8.1.

Does TclTk have large "unlimited" numbers like Python and Ruby? If yes then what is wrong with the second code section below?

The following code has no problem and I understand it.

```
% set a 1234567890
1234567890
% puts $a
1234567890
% expr $a +10
1234567900
% format %d $a
1234567890
% format %5d $a
1234567890
% format %15d $a
     1234567890
```

What is wrong with the following code?

```
% set b 9876543210
9876543210
% puts $b
9876543210
% expr $b + 10
9876543220
% format %d $b
1286608618
% format %5d $b
1286608618
% format %15d $b
     1286608618
```

Why won't the format give proper output? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl has bignums. Has done since 8.5. It uses them anywhere it needs to in its arithmetic code; you should pretend that all integers are bignums (and let Tcl pick whatever storage format to use internally it wants).

The `format` and `scan` commands require a bit of extra work because to support them because they have to also support old code that depended on the clamp-to-range behaviour that was previously common. That means using `ll` as a modifier with the format codes; for example, with `%d`:

```
% format %d 123123123123123123123123
-8893568888133913677
% format %lld 123123123123123123123123
123123123123123123123123

% scan 123123123123123123123123 %d
9223372036854775807
% scan 123123123123123123123123 %lld
123123123123123123123123
```

*This is independent of the field width control.*

```
% format %40d 123123123123123123123123
                    -8893568888133913677
% format %40lld 123123123123123123123123
                123123123123123123123123
```

Comment: So TclTk got bignums like Python and Ruby. Nice illustrative example for the ll. Thank you very much.